# Clearances while rotating the camera

Tags: opengl

I have a quite strange issue. Please, look at these screenshots:

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

[image: img4]

Code of that object:

```
void prostopadloscian(float x, float y, float z, float red, float green, float blue)
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(red, green, blue);

        glNormal3f(-x,-y,-z);
        glVertex3f(-x,-y,-z);
        glNormal3f(x,-y,-z);
        glVertex3f(x,-y,-z);
        glNormal3f(x,-y,z);
        glVertex3f(x,-y,z);
        glNormal3f(-x,-y,z);
        glVertex3f(-x,-y,z);

        glNormal3f(-x,y,-z);
        glVertex3f(-x,y,-z);
        glNormal3f(x,y,-z);
        glVertex3f(x,y,-z);
        glNormal3f(x,y,z);
        glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        glNormal3f(-x,y,z);
        glVertex3f(-x,y,z);

        glNormal3f(-x,y,z);
        glVertex3f(-x,y,z);
        glNormal3f(-x,-y,z);
        glVertex3f(-x,-y,z);
        glNormal3f(-x,-y,-z);
        glVertex3f(-x,-y,-z);
        glNormal3f(-x,y,-z);
        glVertex3f(-x,y,-z);

        glNormal3f(-x,-y,-z);
        glVertex3f(-x,-y,-z);
        glNormal3f(x,-y,-z);
        glVertex3f(x,-y,-z);
        glNormal3f(x,y,-z);
        glVertex3f(x,y,-z);
        glNormal3f(-x,y,-z);
        glVertex3f(-x,y,-z);

        glNormal3f(x,y,z);
        glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        glNormal3f(x,-y,z);
        glVertex3f(x,-y,z);
        glNormal3f(x,-y,-z);
        glVertex3f(x,-y,-z);
        glNormal3f(x,y,-z);
        glVertex3f(x,y,-z);

        glNormal3f(-x,y,z);
        glVertex3f(-x,y,z);
        glNormal3f(-x,-y,z);
        glVertex3f(-x,-y,z);
        glNormal3f(-x,-y,-z);
        glVertex3f(-x,-y,-z);
        glNormal3f(-x,y,-z);
        glVertex3f(-x,y,-z);
    glEnd();
}
    void bed()
    {
        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(-1.6, 0, 4.6);
            prostopadloscian(0.2, 0.25, 0.2, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
        glPopMatrix();
        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(1.6, 0, 4.6);
            prostopadloscian(0.2, 0.25, 0.2, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
        glPopMatrix();
        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(-1.6, 0, -4.6);
            prostopadloscian(0.2, 0.25, 0.2, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
        glPopMatrix();
        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(1.6, 0, -4.6);
            prostopadloscian(0.2, 0.25, 0.2, 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
        glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(0.0, 0.55, 0.0);
            prostopadloscian(2,0.3,5,0.85,0.85,0.95);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
```

my display() function starts at

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); 

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glLoadIdentity();
```

How to get rid of this ugly effect?

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What is your question?

Comment: How to get rid of this ugly effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, those prostopadloscians do look a bit strange. It's hard to say for sure from these shots, but some things to look at:

- Is backface culling enabled?
- If so, are you specifying the vertices in the right order?
- Are your front and back clipping plane not too far apart?
- Does your depth buffer have enough bits for the clipping plane distance you're using?
- Are your normals all pointing the right way? (Hint: no. Unless you're being tricky, each face should need only one `glNormal` call.)

Comment: I haven't set the backface, so it's by default.

Comment: LOL for *"Yeah, those prostopadloscians do look a bit strange."*

Comment: Backface culling is disabled by default. Then my money is on the clipping planes. Are you doing something like near=0.001, far=1000000 by any chance?

Comment: The normals don't make the issue. I can comment it out and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't think they would. But they are wrong regardless -- you'll notice when you try to turn on lighting :)

Comment: @Thomas I don't understand what you are trying to say in the comment with "any chance".

Comment: Never mind the normals. Check the clipping planes. What values are you passing to `glFrustum`?

Comment: I think what @Thomas is trying to say is that you've defined a huge viewing frustum and the limited resolution of Z-Buffer is causing Z-fighting amongst polygons that are close together.

Comment: I use gluLookAt() - gluLookAt(Camera::x(), Camera::y(), Camera::z(), 0.0, -3.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

Comment: That's for the modelview matrix. Surely you're setting a projection matrix as well?

Comment: I did free spaces between these elements and there is no that effect then.

Comment: I do not understand what you're saying, but sounds like it's resolved now?

Comment: Not in all. I did margins like 0.001px and is ok, but it's quite stupid to do it for many objects.

Answer (score 1):

If that effect is intermittent, I would think that Z-fighting might be occurring. Have you tried drawing the table top with [glPolygonOffset](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPolygonOffset.xml)?

Comment: No, I meant call glPolygonOffset(2f, 2f) (try a negative first value if that doesn't work) BEFORE rendering the table top. I am fairly certain that should fix the issue you're having.